# Add native binary to jetpack compose package

Tags: compose-desktop, debian-packaging

My Jetpack Compose Desktop app depends on a proprietary executable that I would like to include in the Debian package.
The closest I'm getting is adding the file as a resource, but that will not set the executable flag.

Is there another way of including files in the packageDeb task, that will preserve the executable flag?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Windows bundling `adb.exe` and some of it's dynamic libraries during packaging. I am trying a custom gradle task to copy the files in to a directory where they'll get bundled in the distributable, but am having trouble with accessing the Compose plugin gradle tasks through the `tasks` container.

Comment: Same thing, I want to include ADB into the desktop app as there is no guarantee that the user has it set up before.